# Connecting to one Ethernet connection disconnects from the other (Debian Buster)

Tags: debian, ethernet, realtek

I am running Debian Buster with GNOME on the HP-AY554TU which has the RTL8101/2/6E Ethernet controller and an RTL8723BE wireless card.

I have installed the latest firmware-realtek package using apt.

When I was using Ubuntu 19.10, I could use USB tethering from my OnePlus 6T AND the Ethernet port (connected to a router) simultaneously.

In Buster, when I turn on (from the GNOME panel) the onboard Ethernet connection, it automatically turns off the USB tethering connection (and vice-versa). I faced the same problem when using Xfce and LXDE.

How can I get both of them to run simultaneously, just like in Ubuntu 19.10?